# Kotlin FragmentStatePagerAdapter shows empty views

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to set up ViewPager adapter inside a fragment to show another fragments. The problem is that when called ViewPager automatically calls the first two fragments while displaying only blank page.

This is how ViewPager is set:

```
class SwipePagerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var pager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipe_pager, container, false)
        pager = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentSwipePager_pager)
        val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        pager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        return view
    }

    private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        override fun getCount(): Int = 3

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
            0 -> MeFragment()
            1 -> AccountFragment()
            3 -> SearchFragment()
            else -> ContactsFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        val frContainer = (activity as MainActivity).findViewById<View>(R.id.activityMain_fragment) as ViewGroup
        frContainer.removeAllViews()
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}
```

This is what I get in logcat:

```
... D/FRG ME: # onCreateView
... D/FRG Account: # onCreateView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, LOL, I have figured it out.
I have set layout for Fragment I used for ViewPager as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentSwipePager_rootScroll"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".SwipePagerFragment">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSwipePager_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem was in "layout_height" property of ScrollView as it was set to "wrap_content" and with no actual content with non-zero height inside it resulted in drawing zero-height line and displaying Fragments contents inside it. Changing "layout_height" to "match_parent" solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add 4 fragments in ViewPager and provided getCount() = 3

override fun getCount(): Int = 4

Also, make changes in Adapter as follows,

```
private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : 
FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getCount(): Int = 4

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> MeFragment()
        1 -> AccountFragment()
        2 -> SearchFragment()
        else -> ContactsFragment()
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that irrelevant to how many Fragments i set in FragmentStatePagerAdapter it displays only blank page while calling the first two of them from getItem (as I can see from Logcat). The code above gives the same result.